# Minecraft Disable fly

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

The goal is to enable flying when the player types `/fly` and disable it when the player types `/dfly`, but when I do `/dfly` nothing happens.

```
    package ts.fl.me;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("plugin started yaya");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("plugin stoped:(");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String lable, String args[]) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fly")) {
                String fly = "fly " + player.getName();
                Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), fly);
                player.setAllowFlight(true);
                player.setFlying(true);
                player.sendMessage(Color.RED + "you are now flying mate");
            }

        }
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("dfly")) {
                if(player.isFlying()){
                    String dfly = "dfly " + player.getName();
                    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), dfly);
                    player.setAllowFlight(false);
                    player.setFlying(false);
                    player.sendMessage("you are no longer flying!");

                }
            }

        }
        return false;

    }


}
```

Comment: I don't find any problem with this code. Check for errors in Player source code

Comment: You have to register your Commands! In the plugin.yml and  I think also in the onEnable()

Comment: You only need to register them if in a command executor. If there in your main class you just have to check what the command label is(The command name label word whatever).  **ALWAYS REGISTER in your plugin.yml** You also don't need to ever access the logger! Just use `System.out.println("TEXT");`

Comment: @Lightspeed360 You **need** the logger. that is why each plugin has its own logger, if you didn't it wouldn't exist or it would be deprecated in the server (if there where backwards compatibility issues) Loggers allow you to do a ton of things more, and some plugins/aplications rely on it to capture outputs etc.  The issue i can see with the code amongst others is called "Copy-paste". You dont have to check twice if the sender is a player, and then get an instance and then check for the command. You can check for the command _name_ in the first if, and voila!

Comment: @fillpant What are these things you can do "a ton more of?" none of my plugins use the logger and work perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lightspeed360 Read my message carefully, after 'ton of things more' im giving an example. And it doesn't break your plugin, but that doesnt mean it is good! The fact that it 'is working' doesnt mean it is coded well, thats why i underlined the use of a loger and i corrected you saying that it is not needed so pationately.
Have a look arround and especially in Bukkit forums where there are plenty of threads on how to use the logger corrently, what it does, how and what you can do with it.

Comment: @fillpant I still see no reason for you to use the logger. :I

Comment: @Lightspeed360 Then you havent done as i recomended :P
With a logger, you can add filters and process the output going through them. Lets now supose that a plugin uses that feature for any reason, all that goes through the logger, will be captured because Loggers enable you to register filters for them (see docs). But your plugin uses the printstream (system.out) so the output doesnt go through the logger so -you guessed it- messages/errors  from your plugin are not registered so -> your plugin does not exist for the other plugin filtering the stream.

Comment: @fillpant So why wouldn't you simply read the console(I'm guessing thats what your reading) with another method no matter system out or logger you can read it? Or simply not listen to these messages as thats not the BEST way to see if a plugin's feater is enabled and somehow implement it? Implement being using Bukkit to #1 check if the plugin is enabled then check if the feature is enabled. Simply implementing it like normal bukkit. No? _Why depend on somthing that has a possibility of failing?_

Comment: _**For the question**_ #1: We should minimize code the best we can! So check for _CommandName_>_SenderIsPlayer(Create a boolean before command check maybe)_ Then for the disabling of fly you can check 'if (player.getAllowFlight())' _**As your currect fly disabling command checks if there in the air currently instead of if they have fly enabled!**_ You can also simply have 1 command and disable fly if fly is enabled and if else is called set fly which also might minimize. '_**Those are just some ideas so whatever you want to do is fine.**_'

Comment: @Lightspeed360 You missed my point. I never sugested that logger is used to check if a plugin is enabled or if a feature is enabled, don't try to put words in my mouth -or hands in this instance-. Unfortunately this is a very limited space to type messages as i want, and show examples. Not to mention that we are out of topic. If you wish to continue this, feel free to find me at forums.bukkit.com (i'm **mine-care**) and start a conversation, or post a thread.
Also, about #1 as a general rule, you should not minimise code as you can if that compramises security, reliability and/or efficiency.

Comment: @fillpant If your removing security/reliability you just don't do it? Id rather have 100 more lines to make sure my security is good. _**For this**_ What is 'Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), fly);' doing there? Won't this cause the console to be forced to run command when uneeded to?

Comment: @Lightspeed360 I am not refering to this perticular case. I have many sugestions of improvment for the post myself, but i added to what you said that as a general rule, it is not better to minimize lines of code if that compramises security or makes the code unreadable. In some cases, yes you are right. 1000 lines of code may do the equivalant of 10 lines in an unnessesarily complex way. But its hard to generalize, and state that for all codes, the least the code the better the snipet/program.

Answer (score 0):

For the `dfly` command (according to your code), the player's permission to fly will only be revoked if he is currently actively flying. So if a player is not flying (e.g. on the ground), but has the *ability* to fly, the `dfly` command won't do anything, which is what I am assuming you mean by nothing happening when using the command.

If you intend for the `dfly` command to also take away the player's permission to fly even if they are not currently flying (but have the ability to do so), you could simply remove the "`if (player.isFlying())`" condition. This would reflect the same behavior of the `fly` command, which doesn't check whether the player is *not* currently flying before giving them the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving a example of what I made :D

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public boolean onCommandFly(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("fly")) { 
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        if(sender instanceof Player) {
            if(p.hasPermission("smpenhance.fly")) {
                if(args.length == 1) {
                    if (args.length > 1) {
                        p.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fToo many arguments!"));
                    } else {
                        if(p.isFlying() == true) {
                            Player po = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                            po.setAllowFlight(false);
                            po.setFlying(false);
                            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fFlight disabled for &b" + po + "&r"));
                        } else {
                            Player po = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                            po.setAllowFlight(true);
                            po.setFlying(true);
                            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fFlight enabled for &b" + po + "&r"));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if(p.isFlying() == true) {
                        p.setAllowFlight(false);
                        p.setFlying(false);
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fFlight disabled"));
                    } else {
                        p.setAllowFlight(true);
                        p.setFlying(true);
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fFlight enabled"));
                    }
                    p.setAllowFlight(true);
                    p.setFlying(true);
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &fFlight enabled"));
                }
                
                
            } else {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefix + " &4&lSORRY BUT NO PERMS DUDE!"));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(prefix + ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&4Player only command!"));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I NOT TESTED IT YET BUT 'theoretically' IT SHOULD WORK!

Comment: You can [edit] to add info or explanation. Because unexplained, untested code-only answers have a noticably lower chance at upvotes. (And I think your caps-lock is broken or acting opposite to what you want....).